# How do I position a side section or div in relation to nav bar?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout

I have the layout as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvHxb.jpg

I have added a side section just below the nav bar. I want the side section to be placed in relation to the nav bar but it takes its position in relation to the header. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Here is my html code and css

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.header {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 14%;
  width: 100%;
}

img.nav-action-image {
  width: 14px;
  height: auto;
}

nav a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  color: #d1e231;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #bff000;
}

nav a.active {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #bab86c;
  color: #37412a;
}

.navigation-bar {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.action-block {
  height: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class=header>
  </header>
  <nav class=navigation-bar>
    <a href="#menu"><img class="nav-action-image" src="menu_icon.png" /></a>
    <a class="active" href="#Summary">Summary</a>
    <a href="#Summary2">Preferences</a>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <div class="action-block">
    hello
  </div>
</body>
```

you can see that in the css, the code for action-block class aligns from the header instead of the nav bar. I want it to align from the nav bar. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: Hello, just remove the absolute positioning of the .navigation-bar class in your css and add a display:block, it should work.

Comment: where exactly do you want your action block aligned ? It already is aligned with the nav tag.

Comment: it is aligned becuase i set the margin with relation position of header. i want to be with relation of nav bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `position:absolute` from `body` and `nav`.

The below css will clear the floating elements inside `nav` which will give it a height of its content.

```
nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

.header {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 14%;
  width: 100%;
}

img.nav-action-image {
  width: 14px;
  height: auto;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both
}

nav a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  color: #d1e231;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #bff000;
}

nav a.active {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #bab86c;
  color: #37412a;
}

.navigation-bar {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: yellow;
}

.action-block {
  height: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  background: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
  </header>
  <nav class="navigation-bar">
    <a href="#menu"><img class="nav-action-image" src="menu_icon.png" /></a>
    <a class="active" href="#Summary">Summary</a>
    <a href="#Summary2">Preferences</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="action-block">
    hello
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using a absolute element relative to another element, then the parent must have `position: relative`. With this in mind replace your body css with:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

If using floats in the nav (the anchor element), use a `clear: both` at the end likte this

```
.navigation-bar {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.navigation-bar::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
nav a {
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d1e231;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #bff000;
}
nav a.active {
    background-color: #bab86c;
    color: #37412a;
}
```